# How do I do a secondary lookup in the middle of a foreach loop in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm sure this must be really straight forward but I am not a dev and have been struggling with this for a while, hoping someone can help.

Basically I have an 2D array of invoices:

```
Date | Total | Currency
2020-08-17 | 500 | GBP
2020-08-15 | 1000 | USD
```

I want to add a 4th column to standardise the total into one currency, GBP in this case.

I have a secondary table of exchange rates, like this (but lets assume it could have other exchange rates in the future):

```
Date | USD-to-GBP
2020-08-18 | 0.75
2020-08-17 | 0.745
2020-08-16 | 0.749
2020-08-15 | 0.740
```

I am using a foreach to go through the invoices array and and have an if statement to say 'if currency is GBP then total stays as it is' but I need to say 'if currency is USD then lookup the date in the exchange rates table that matches the invoice date and get the exchange rate'

Here is the code so far:

```
function GBPTotal() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Getting data from the zapier populated spreadsheet
  var receivablesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("zap receivable");
  var receivablesLastRow = receivablesSheet.getLastRow();
  var receivablesData = receivablesSheet.getRange(2,1,receivablesLastRow-1,4).getValues();
  
  // Getting data from the exchange rates table
  var exchangeRateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Exchange Rates");
  var exchangeRateLastRow = exchangeRateSheet.getLastRow();
  var exchangeRateData = exchangeRateSheet.getRange(2,1,5,3).getValues();
  
  var totalInGBPArray = [];
  receivablesData.forEach(function(receivablesRow){
    
    var total = receivablesRow[2];
    var currency = receivablesRow[3];
    
    // Switch to detect the currency and act accordingly
   switch (currency) {
   case "GBP":
     var TotalInGBP = total;
     break;
   case "USD":
     /**** HELP - EXCHANGE RATE LOOKUP IN HERE *****/
     break;
    }
   
    receivablesRow.push(TotalInGBP);
    totalInGBPArray.push([TotalInGBP]);
    
});

//Logger.log(totalInGBPArray);

receivablesSheet.getRange(2,5,receivablesLastRow-1,1).setValues(totalInGBPArray);

}
```

I was looking at map as it seems to be the most performant solution but I am not going to be working with big data sets really so maybe I should just accept whatever is easiest to get my head around.

Comment: This can easily be done via formula ? Would you accept a formula solution ?

Comment: Shouldn't you also check for date?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using a simple formula:

```
=if(AND(C3<>"GBP",isnumber(match(A3,'Exchange Rates'!$A$2:$A,0))),B3*index('Exchange Rates'!$B$2:$B,match(A3,'Exchange Rates'!$A$2:$A,0)),B3)
```

### Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the awesome suggestion but this is part of a bigger automation piece. Zapier pulling info from the finance package and putting into sheets, then running some app script so I don't have to keep copying and pasting formula when a new invoice is raised, then this data is being reported in Google Data Studio.

I'd have used a vlookup so you've taught me something new, but not what I'm after sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to compare the two dates and retrieve the corresponding exchange rate:

```
case "USD":
  var date = receivablesRow[1];
  var exchangeRate = exchangeRateData.find(exchangeRateRow => exchangeRateRow[0].getTime() === date.getTime())[1];
  var TotalInGBP = total * exchangeRate;
  break;
```

**Note**: I'm assuming that the date in exchange rates is in column A, and the one in the invoices is in column B for their respective sheets. Change the indexes if that's not the case.